# constructor-arg and property together in bean definition

Tags: java, spring, properties, javabeans

```
<bean id="cObject" scope="request" class="x.y.z.CClass"/>
<bean id="bObject" scope="request" class="x.y.z.BClass"/>
<bean id="aObject" scope="request" class="x.y.z.AClass">
    <constructor-arg ref="bObject" />
    <property name="cRef" ref="cObject" />
</bean>
```

aObject.cRef is not getting set for some reason. Note that constructor-arg and property are used in the same definition. I have not seen an example / post with similar feature.

Comment: Which version of Spring? Works fine for me with Spring 3.0.5. Also, try setting just one or the other. My guess is that your problem has nothing to do with mixing property and constructor-arg.

Comment: This syntax is fine. Are you sure you're not trying to use `cRef` from *within* the constructor, because it won't have been set by that point.

Comment: Starting with a single lower case letter for a bean can cause troubles with Spring, Jackson, and others that rely upon the bean specification. If you changed the property to myCRef does it workaround the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Mixing `<constructor-arg>` and `<property>` is generally a bad idea.

There is only one good reason for using `<constructor-arg>`, and that is to create immutable objects.

However, your objects are not immutable if you can set their properties. Don't use `<constructor-arg>`. Redesign the class, use an initializer method annotated with `@PostConstruct` if you need to apply some logic at bean creation time.

Comment: That take makes sense.
Fixed by using autowire="byName" and properties. Somehow when struts instantiates the bean it was not invoking the bean using the custom constructor. This fix is more desirable.

Answer (score 3):

On same sources my colleague discover:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Error creating bean with name 'service.MenuService#0'
  defined in class path resource [spring-beans/integrator.xml]:
  Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name
  arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

while my host, test and production servers have no such error.

With:

```
<bean class="service.MenuService">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="#{user}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.lang.String" value="#{password}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" type="java.lang.String" value="#{uri}"/>
    <property name="system" value="OPRT"/>
    <property name="client" value="OPRT"/>
</bean>
```

while there are only one 3-args constructor in bean.

The reason to use constructor - it perform some additional actions on non-Spring library by invoking `init()` method. And set args as fields.

So I change `spring-beans.xml` to:

```
<bean class="service.MenuService" init-method="init">
    <property name="login" value="#{user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="#{password}"/>
    <property name="httpsUrl" value="#{uri}"/>
    <property name="system" value="OPRT" />
    <property name="client" value="OPRT" />
</bean>
```

Take attention to `init-method=` part.

**UPDATE** After all I wrote simple XML config and step through Spring source code in debugger. Seems that with Spring 3.x it's possible to combine **constructor-arg** and **property** in XML **bean** definition (check **doCreateBean** in `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java`, which call **createBeanInstance** and **populateBean** next).

See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149378/both-constructor-and-setter-injection-together-in-spring/