# Can spring initialze child-bean from yml when parent that has constructor-arg, child has more members

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Say i have a parent class with one member:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;


    public void setName(String aName) {
        this.name = aName;
    }

    public String getName() {
         return this.name;
    }
}
```

I have a configuration class like:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ApplicationConfig {

  private final List<Person> persons = 
      new ArrayList<Person>();



  public List<Person> getPersons() {
    return persons;
}
```

And i want to initialize a set of people from my application.yml file:

```
persons:
 - Bob
 - Eva
 - Robin
```

I have found that this works provided Person is defined as:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(String aName) {
      this.name = aName;
    }

    public String getName() {
         return this.name;
    }
}
```

But it breaks down as soon as i introduce Employee extends Person, where employee has employeeNumber.
Ideally i would like to do this -but that is not valid yml:

```
persons:
 - Bob
 - Eva
 - Robin
employees:
 - Tim
   employeeNum: 123
```

Comment: You can pass the pre-poluated list of persons on the constructor when you initialized it. You can read that list from the yml file as well.

Comment: @ royalGhost I dont understand, do you mean have Spring populate a list of Strings and than use that to initialize a list of persons?

Comment: Yes, you can store list of persons on external file such as application.yml

Comment: @royalGhost, i am storing the persons in an external file. My question is about naming the member name explicitly in the yml or leaving it to Spring to figure it out.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to use the verbose version

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150181/constructor-arg-and-property-together-in-bean-definition

Answer (score 0):

So far i have not found a way to do this other then define both parend and child class with getters and setters (so no constructor arguments!), and defining the .yml as:

```
persons:
  - name: Bob
  - name: Eva
  - name: Robin
employees:
  - name Tim
    employeeNum: 123
```